# How to get updated state in second useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using two useEffect in a single component because there are two types of dependencies. In the first useEffect I'm updating a state, but I'm not able to get the updated state in a second useEffect console.

If I'm logging it outside of useEffect then it's working fine but I need it in useEffect.

**Note: Click on test button then check console.log there is getting initial state value instead of updated value.**

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function MyComponent() {
  const [editData, setEditData] = useState("initData");

  const depdency1 = "depdency1";
  const depdency2 = "depdency2";

  useEffect(() => {
    mufuction();
  }, [depdency1]);

  const mufuction = () => {
    setEditData("Updated Data");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("editData", editData);
  }, [depdency2]);

  return <div className="App"></div>;
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/state-issue-with-useeffect-y737y2)

Comment: You misspelled "dependency"

Comment: Also, your second `useEffect` is missing the `editData` state in its dependency array. Code Sandbox tells you with via ESLint > _"React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'editData'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)"_ The Second `useEffect` will not trigger when the `editData` state is updated. So you will not receive a log message.

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of this code? What is it supposed to do realistically?

Comment: I need updated state value in second useEffect.

Comment: Which state data?

Comment: editData state data @Mr. Polywhirl

Comment: You already updated its state in the first `useEffect`. What is supposed to happen in the second one?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("editData", editData);
}, [depdency2]);
```

The `dependency2` value will not change, therefore you'll only see the `console.log` with the value of the first render.

If you want to trigger the second `useEffect` when `editData` is altered, set the dependancy array to contains `editData`:

```
useEffect(() => {       
    mufuction();
}, [ ]);                                // RUN ON MOUNT

useEffect(() => {
    onsole.log("editData", editData);
}, [editData]);                         // RUN WHEN editData changes
```

---

Small runnable demo:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const [editData, setEditData] = useState("initData");

    useEffect(() => {
      mufuction();
    }, [ ]);  // RUN ON MOUNT

    const mufuction = () => {
      setEditData("Updated Data");
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log("editData", editData);
    }, [editData]); // RUN WHEN editData changes

    return <div className="App"></div>;
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

```
editData initData
editData Updated Data
```

Answer (score 1):

The second `useEffect` is not running when `editData` is updated because `editData` is not listed as one of its dependencies. The following code should work:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function MyComponent() {
  const [editData, setEditData] = useState("initData");

  useEffect(() => {
    mufuction();
  }, []);

  const mufuction = () => {
    setEditData("Updated Data");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("editData", editData);
  }, [editData]);

  return <div className="App"></div>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's redesign the layout of this component. You have a state. That state has an initial value. Let's log the value of this state each time it is updated. Once when the component is created, and again when it is mounted.

I included both a functional and class component version.

#### Function component version

```js
const { useCallback, useEffect, useState } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState("Initial Value");

  const updateDataState = useCallback(() => {
    setData("Updated Value"); // Mutate the data
  }, [data]);

  // componentDidMount
  useEffect(() => {
    updateDataState();
  }, []);

  // componentDidUpdate
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Data State:", data); // Log the value
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{data}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
  .render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

#### Class component version

```js
const { Component } = React;

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = { data: "Initial Value" };
     this.componentDidUpdate(); // Not needed, but force-logs initial state
  }

  updateDataState() {
    this.setState((state) => ({
      ...state,
      data: "Updated Value" // Mutate the data 
    }));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateDataState();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("Data State:", this.state.data); // Log the value
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>{this.state.data}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
  .render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```